# A JavaScript Framework for Instance/Static Variables?

Tags: javascript

Here is the current method I use, where everything is either all public or private.  However I would like to differentiate between static and instance. How would I add this in?

`obj` holds the class or object have you, and config_module determines what type of module this is.

All private, All public  ( a collection of statics ), or instance based on a constructor method.

If I do use an instance based, how do I differentiate between statics and instance based properties?

```
   $P.support = $P.parsel = function (obj, config_module) {
        $R.Parsel[obj.Name] = obj;

        // all properties are private

        if (!config_module) {
            return undefined;
        }

        // all properties are public

        if (config_module === true) {
            return obj;
        }

        // constructor based, all properties are public

        if (config_module === 'constructor') {
            var object_public;
            if (obj.constructor) {
                object_public = obj.constructor;
                delete obj.constructor;
            }
            $A.someKey(obj, function (val, key) {

                // like this ?

                if (/^s_/.test(key)) {
                    object_public[key] = val;

                // like this ?

                } else if (/^p_/.test(key)) {
                    object_public.prototype[key] = val;
                } else {
                    object_public.prototype[key] = val;
                }

            });
            return object_public;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have (pseudo) static stuff by adding properties to the constructor:

```
function Something(){}
Something.getStaticFoo = function(){ return 'foo'; }
Something.getStaticFoo();
var instance = new Something();
instance.getStaticFoo(); // error
```

If I understand your code, that's the same as `object_public[key] = val;`.

Comment: well...if I add things to the prototpye they are "static" as well.  That is there is only one per "class".  What about instance based variables, am I required to use `this` ?

Comment: Good point about the prototype; in that case you'd have the methods available on all instances, but it might be confusing because those methods will have access to `this` (meaning each individual instance). Is that what you're asking about instance-based variables?

Comment: that's right the prototype method has access to instance based this variables... and yes that's what I'm asking about.

Comment: I'm a little confused... You're not required to use `this` inside instance methods; you are required to use `this` to be able to access instance variables.

Comment: I'm looping through properties in an object literal and adding them to the prototype chain, this makes them "static" variables.  I was asking how I could pull instance variables off the object literal ( or more precisely "signatures" b.c. the value is likely different for each instantiation, and add them to the constructor function I return.  I think this is impossible to do in a simple way.  I re-stated the question here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758986/improving-a-class-framewok-for-js