# Improving a "class" framewok for JS?

Tags: javascript

Please do not debate wether this approach is valid, some do it, some don't.

Here is my super small class framework.  Note that by simply returning nothing/undefined I make it completely private statics ( yes this has a use ).  Or I can return everything and make it completely public statics.

Very simple, about 4 lines of code.  Now the more complicated part - see below.

`config_module` determines what type of klass it is.

Implementation:

```
$P.klass = function (obj, config_module) {

    // all properties are private ( there is no access )

    if (!config_module) {
        return undefined;
    }

    // all properties are public and static ( there is no instance )

    if (config_module === true) {
        return obj;
    }

    // constructor based, all properties are public and static/instance

    if (config_module === 'constructor') {
        var object_public;
        if (obj.constructor) {
            object_public = obj.constructor;
            delete obj.constructor;
        }
        $A.someKey(obj, function (val, key) {
            object_public.prototype[key] = val;
        });
        return object_public;
    }
};
```

If I want to make it an instance based instead of statics I just look for an aptly named constructor property which I return and then put the rest of the properties on the prototype chain.

This works well, I can even use instance variables using `this` as shown below

```
    var SForm = $A.klass({

        Name: 'SForm',

        // static based

        S: {
            google:    'https://plus.google.com/_/favicon?domain=',
            pre_url:   /(http:)|(https:)\/\//,
            domain:    /:\/\/(www\.)?([\.a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/

            // ... blah

        },
        constructor : function (form_elements) {
            this.form_obj = {};
            $A.someKey(form_elements, function (val) {
                if (val.type !== 'checkbox') {
                    this.form_obj[val.name] = val.value;
                } else if (val.type === 'checkbox') {
                    this.form_obj[val.name] = val.checked;
                }
            }, this);
        },
        get: function (key) {
            return this.form_obj[key];
        },
        set: function (key, value) {
            this.form_obj[key] = value;
        },
        getObj: function () {
            return this.form_obj;

        // ... blah

    }, 'constructor');
```

Now to the question:

Is there a way to list instance variables explicitly.  Instead of setting them in the constructor, can I put them in the framework some how?

Comment: have a feeling https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties may help you.

Comment: as in, if you were to create your properties as a batch, then you could store them somewhere too, but not sure if that is what you are after.

Comment: @danp - I don't follow what you are saying?

Comment: ... but no the reference is not what I'm aiming for.